# Camera and gallery in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin

I have an application where you need to upload a photograph taken from the camera or the gallery, if you allow me to enter the camera without problems and take the photo, likewise enter the gallery and select one, but when I want to see it in an image redirects me to my main screen

Comment: What issues are you facing?

Comment: we can't debug code that we can't see.   Please post the relevant code.

Comment: It seems that I closed the application, but I change the view when selecting an image of the gallery and take a picture.

Comment: @MarcoGarcia Please show your code, we can't know what happened without it.

Comment: file:///Users/mkbeer/Desktop/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202019-06-07%20a%20la(s)%2013.47.20.png This method of calling the camera or the gallery has been chosen by the user.

Comment: file:///Users/mkbeer/Desktop/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202019-06-07%20a%20la(s)%2013.51.49.png This other method is where you take the picture, all right, I open the camera takes the picture but when I select "UsePhoto" cell phone sends me to another view.

Comment: @MarcoGarcia Can you provide some code or a sample to help us understand your issue?

Comment: avatar.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer(async (view) =>
            {
                var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Seleccionar Foto", "Cancelar", null, "Cámara", "Galería");
                if (action == "Cámara")
                {
                    setting.TakePicture();
                }
                if (action == "Galería")
                {
                    setting.PickPicture();
                }
            }));

Comment: This part is to open either the camera or gallery.

Comment: All right up there, I open either the camera or the gallery, I can take a good picture but when I put that I need to use that image I change the screen without giving me continue, the same happens when I select a photo from the gallery.

Comment: await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error",
                    "No se otorgaron permisos para accesar a las fotos.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
            {
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                CompressionQuality = 30
            });

Comment: This part is of the gallery's method, the only thing it does is open the gallery.

Comment: if (file == null) { return; } byte[] array; using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) { int count = 0; file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream); array = memoryStream.ToArray(); while (count < 10) { if (array.Count() == 0) { file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream); array = memoryStream.ToArray(); await Task.Delay(1000);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
            User.Foto = array;
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(array);
            var image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            FotoPerfil = image;

Comment: Finally there is this part where it verifies if the file file is not null to transform it into an image and be able to show it in an Image that is inside my xaml, but it is not shown, it just takes me out of that screen and sends me to the start page .

Comment: In the same way I have a chat where I can send videos or images, the chat and that part of the images or videos worked very well, I do not know when it started to fail, but it also sends me another send back to the home screen. Any idea what it is or how can I solve it?